# Shape key driver not working with IK bones

Tags: bones, shape-keys, inverse-kinematics, graph-editor, axis

Blender version 2.79: I configured a shape key driver for when the leg rotates in X, to repair the "shoulders", but the problem is that the repair shape key shows all the time, even when the bone is not rotated. Here is the file:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try some or all of the following things:

- Unlock the shapekeys:

[image]

- In your *Driver Editor*, choose *Type > Averaged Value*:

[image]

- Create a *Modifier > Generator* with a *X* value of -1:

[image]

Comment: I did this, but it looks like the shape key doesn't go from 0 to 1000 when the bone rotates, i rotate the bone and it just makes a little bit of the repair, when i click in that button unlock shapekey, the shapekey shows all the time, when i click on it again, the shapekey just shows a little bit, even if the bone is rotated at maximum.

Comment: maybe select the driver curve and rotate it to see its effect, your bone doesn't rotate more than several degrees